# Playing Video on Kivy in Raspberry pi

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, kivy, raspbian

I am using kivy on Raspberry pi (Raspbian). I want to play video. The video is loading but playing very slow. What i have to do to play the video without hang.

Comment: Code i used to play video in kivy.                                                              https://pythontic.com/app/kivy/videoplayer

Comment: Please provide code examples in your question not in link, because links are not permanent.